# Android Voice Recognition

Tags: android

Before experimenting the voice recognition feature of Android I read the documentation provided by Android Developer site. Which tells us how to initiate the voice recognition activity for result which will return the result back in a callback. But what I have not implemented any such thing. what I have done is described below.

1. Create a simple EditText in an activity.
2. Now tap that EditText and keypad will appear.
3. Now tap the speak button on keypad.
4. Voice recognition activity will be started.
5. For example I speak "hello"
6. Voice recognition activity recognized my "hello" and this "hello" word is appeared in my EditText in my activity.
7. Could some please explain my how does it happened. how android put the corresponding word into my EditText where i did not do any voice recognition coding.

Thanks
Dalvin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "keypad" Activity (built-in) did this for you and sent the text to the element, which had the focus. You need the approach you mentioned to do it without the keypad.

Comment: Please be so kind to mark the question as answered (the checkmark below my answer score)